# Matrix Manipulation Question

Tags: matrices

Given that **A** $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\-3\\-5\end{bmatrix}$ and **A** $\begin{bmatrix}1\\4\\-2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ find **A** $\begin{bmatrix}1 && 1\\-2 && 4\\1 && -2\end{bmatrix}$

Not really sure how to approach this question. Help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** $A[v_1 v_2] = [Av_1 Av_2]$

Comment: Oh wow, thank you very much. I have just started learning Matrix Algebra and this popped up under an extension question in my workbook... is there a rule or something that I can google to understand the intuition behind this?

Comment: I think what you want to do is understand how you multiply two matrices. Once you understand that, the solution should be immediate.

Comment: The wikipedia article about matrix multiplication (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) provides a lot of intuitive ways to understand matrix multiplications.

Answer (score 1):

To get more intuition for working with matrices, it might also help to consider a $n$ x $m$ matrix **A** as a representation of a linear transformation from an m-dimensional vector space $V$ to an n-dimensional vector space $W$, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_transformation

**A** is not just a table of numbers with related operations; it produces elements of $W$ when fed with elements of $V$.

If you feed **A** with one $V$ element, it produces one $W$ element; if you feed it with two, it produces two. Also note that the linearity of the transformation implies (and is defined by) that for $v_1, v_2 \in V$ and $\lambda, \mu$ scalars, **A** fed with $\lambda v_1 + \mu v_2$ will produce $\lambda Av_1 + \mu Av_2$, thus: $A(\lambda v_1 + \mu v_2) = \lambda A(v_1) + \mu A(v_2)$